# SVG additional margin

Tags: html, css, svg

Can someone explain to me why there's that extra 3px of space between the 1st div and the 2nd div here:

http://jsbin.com/aSoRoC/1/edit

```
<body style="margin: 0">
    <div style="background-color: green;">
        <svg style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 0;" width="600" height="40" fill="#f00"></svg>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 600px; height: 40px;"></div>
</body>
```

It can be fixed if you put `height: 40px;` on the first div, but I'm not understanding why that's necessary.  This happens universally across Chrome, FireFox, and IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SVG is an inline element, and the default vertical-align for inline elements is baseline.

```
svg {
    vertical-align: middle; /* or anything other than baseline */
}
```

Comment: Weird, thanks.  Any benefit over doing what you suggested over just making it a `block` element (aside from the obvious, assuming I only plan to have 1 SVG element on my page)?

Comment: Hmm, and why doesn't a `span` have that problem (or any other inline element)?

Comment: Ah, I see `textarea` exhibits the same issue... quote from mozilla docs *The baseline of some replaced elements, like <textarea> is not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with this keyword may change from one browser to the other.*

Comment: Provided you only have 1, either way will work.  Altering the display property *will* alter what other styles you can use on the element (for instance centering an inline element is done with text-align, while block elements are centered using margins).